# InitiateShutdown, can't understand a value passed to the function

Tags: c, winapi, shutdown

I don't understand the difference between shutting down a computer and powering off a computer with this function. I'm looking at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376872(v=vs.85).aspx
Specifically, I don't understand `SHUTDOWN_NOREBOOT`.

- `SHUTDOWN_NOREBOOT`
  `0x00000010 (0x10)`
  The computer is shut down but is not powered down or rebooted.
- `SHUTDOWN_POWEROFF`
  `0x00000008 (0x8)`
  The computer is shut down and powered down.
- `SHUTDOWN_RESTART`
  `0x00000004 (0x4)`
  The computer is shut down and rebooted.

If the computer is not powered down nor is it going to be rebooted, then what is the purpose? Is `SHUTDOWN_NOREBOOT` synonymous with having the computer sleep?

Comment: The processor is simply halted but the machine is still powered. This was the normal case back in times when there was no ACPI.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The documentation for the equivalent option for [`ExitWindowsEx`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376868(v=vs.85).aspx), `EWX_SHUTDOWN`, is a bit clearer. (Emphasis mine)

> Shuts down the system to *a point at which it is safe to turn off the power*. All file buffers have been flushed to disk, and all running processes have stopped.

In days of yore, PCs did not have the ability to turn themselves off, and there was no `EWX_POWEROFF` option.  When you shut down Windows, it would either drop you back into DOS, or (if there was no outer DOS environment) it would put up a black screen with orange text reading "[It's now safe to turn off your computer](http://www.howtogeek.com/181295/yes-its-okay-to-shut-down-your-computer-with-the-power-button/)."  That was your cue to flip the [big red switch](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20080513-00/?p=22343) on the side of the case.

Nowadays, this shut-down mode is obsolete but preserved for backward compatibility.  I wouldn't be surprised if Windows 10 could still bring up the "It's now safe to turn off your computer" screen.

Comment: I could think of some industrial use cases where I'd want to shut down so "buffers are flushed and processes have stopped" but still leave the power on so as not to disturb peripherals living off the same power supply. It still has it's uses.

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, Windows is no longer actually capable of shutting down without powering off.  The request is accepted for backwards compatibility but the system powers off anyway.  (I think support may have been removed in Windows Vista, which according to my research was the first version to require ACPI hardware.)